# While try to authenticate my login I am getting error "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError "

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jwt

I am getting error **"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null"**

I try to debug my code but cant understand cause of this error.

I am getting this error in my AuthService class in line ;

```
Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));
```

Here is my AuthService class ;

```
@Service
public class AuthService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private JwtProvider jwtProvider;
    .........................................
    public String login(LoginRequest loginRequest){
        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(),
                loginRequest.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
        return jwtProvider.generateToken(authenticate);

    }
}
```

SecurityConfig file:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

AuthController class :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class AuthController {

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest){
        return authService.login(loginRequest);

    }
}
```

LoginRequest dto :

```
public class LoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;

    ...getters and setters...
}
```

User model:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String userName;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String email;

    ...getters and setters...
}
```

UserRepository Interface:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findByUserName(String username);

}
```

JwtProvider:

```
@Service
public class JwtProvider {

    private Key key;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        key = Keys.secretKeyFor(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512);

    }
    public String generateToken(Authentication authentication){
        User principal = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(principal.getUsername())
                .signWith(key)
                .compact();
    }
}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl class:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUserName(username).orElseThrow(()->
                new UsernameNotFoundException("No user name found named " + username));
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(),
                user.getPassword(),
                true,true,true,true,
                getAuthorities("ROLE_USER"));
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role_user) {
        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role_user));
    }
}
```

and my application.properties :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/photoblog?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=...username...
spring.datasource.password=...password...
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `SecurityConfig` class you are overriding the method `authenticationManager()` which is responsible to fetch the AuthenticationManager but inside this method, you are calling the bean`super.authenticationManagerBean()` which creates the AuthenticationManager bean.

Change `authenticationManager()` to `authenticationManagerBean()`

```
@Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManager--

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManagerBean--

Comment: You are a genius bro! Thanks !